# error while running hibernate application

Tags: hibernate

console error goes as follows, i am trying a simple application to know how collections are persisted in the database using hibernate. i am using eclipse, hibernate 3.3. as far as my knowledge goes i did it correct. but console error says that i am wrong.

```
21:33:51,354  INFO Version:15 - Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
21:33:51,363  INFO Environment:560 - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
21:33:51,364  INFO Environment:593 - hibernate.properties not found
21:33:51,366  INFO Environment:771 - Bytecode provider name : javassist
21:33:51,369  INFO Environment:652 - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
21:33:51,416  INFO Version:14 - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
21:33:51,417  INFO Configuration:1474 - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
21:33:51,418  INFO Configuration:1451 - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
21:33:51,475  INFO Configuration:1589 - Configured SessionFactory: null
21:33:51,477  INFO HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister:53 - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
21:33:51,510  INFO AnnotationBinder:419 - Binding entity from annotated class: com.hibernate.CollectionDemo.UserDetail
21:33:51,533  INFO EntityBinder:422 - Bind entity com.hibernate.CollectionDemo.UserDetail on table USER_DETAIL_COLLECTIONS
21:33:51,562  INFO AnnotationConfiguration:369 - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: USER_DETAIL_COLLECTIONS, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(listOfAddress)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1149)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1334)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at com.hibernate.CollectionDemo.TestUserDetail.main(TestUserDetail.java:15)
```

and my model class goes here

```
package com.hibernate.CollectionDemo;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="USER_DETAIL_COLLECTIONS")
public class UserDetail
{
    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Address.class)
    private Set<Address> listOfAddress=new HashSet<Address>();

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Set<Address> getListOfAddress() {
        return listOfAddress;
    }

    public void setListOfAddress(Set<Address> listOfAddress) {
        this.listOfAddress = listOfAddress;
    }
}
```

here contains the address class which will be embedded in the userdetail class

```
package com.hibernate.CollectionDemo;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Address 

{
    private String city;
    private String streetName;
    private String pincode;
    private String State;
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }
    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }
    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        State = state;
    }

}
```

here goes my config file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <!--  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">TESTSCHEMA</property> -->

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup --> 
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- name of the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="com.hibernate.CollectionDemo.UserDetail"/>

        <!--<mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Person.hbm.xml"/>

    -->
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html), @ElementCollection was introduced with JPA 2.0. Hibernate 3.3. implements JPA 1, that's why using this construct is not expected to work.

Problem can be solved by updating to the newer Hibernate version. One option is to update at least to [3.6.10](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/3.6.10.Final/) (which is newest and probably last 3.x) - likely it makes sense to go right away to Hibernate [4.x](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/).